# Angularjs : Apply bold style to a character inside ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a list :

```
$scope.list = ["test/test1/test2/test3","test3/test5/test6"];
```

I would like to apply **bold** style to `/` characters when displaying the list :

```
<div ng-repeat="path in list">
   <p style="font-weight:bold">{{path}}</p>
</div>
```

Do you have any ideas how can I achieve this ?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/4696/)

Comment: Not possible in your above scenario unless you separate them to fall in first or last of an element to declare them via `:after` or `:before`.

Comment: Create simple highlight filter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it simply with str.replace  http://jsfiddle.net/k18vgtvw/

```
 <p style="font-weight:bold" ng-bind-html-unsafe="csc(path)"></p>
```

controller

```
  $scope.csc = function(path) {
    return path.replace(/\//g, "<span style='color:red'>/</span>");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do this. First I'd add a function to your controller, let's say it's called boldSlashes.

```
function boldSlashes(path) {
     return path.replace("/","<b>/</b>")
}
```

Then change your html to be:

```
<div ng-repeat="path in list" ng-bind-html>
   boldSlashes({{path}})
</div>
```

The ng-bind-html tells angular to treat the contents as html and not escape it.

You also have to inject ngSanitize into you module in order to use ng-bind-html.

So wherever you create your module, add ngSanitize to the dependencies like:

angular.module('myApp',[ngSanitize])

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to do but I separated out individual elements. Also the jsfiddle font the bold font looks exactly the same on the / character.

http://jsfiddle.net/3a2duqg4/
1. Updated the view to a list
2. Changed the array to have an individual item per section
3. Added styles to the "/" and realized the font bold property with the fiddle default font didn't look any different.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li class="list" ng-repeat="path in list">{{path}} <span>/</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Added the items to a list rather than a paragraph and added some styles. I updated your array to have one value per array item as well.

Let me know if this helps! :)

Comment: Sorry I can't see any difference with the provided fiddle

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = ["test/test1/test2/test3","test3/test5/test6"];
    $scope.updateString = function(s) {
     return s.replace(/\//g, '<span class="bold">/</span>');
    };
}
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="path in list">
      <p ng-bind-html-unsafe="updateString(path)"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```